# MySQL Performance of recreating a view often

Tags: mysql, performance, view

I'm currently involved in a small project, where a report has to be created every 30 minutes. The SQL for the report must be stored as a view in the MySQL database, and currently the view will be updated when the application is updated through the update-process of the server it's running on. However, just for code-changes this update-process doesn't need to be run. Since the SQL changes quite often, and the update-process is kind of cumbersome, I'm wondering if it would be a performance issue, if the view is simply recreated everytime before a report is created, so every 30 minutes? (The SQL can't just be executed directly.) This way only the new code needs to be deployed, but the server-update-process doesn't need to be run. Since it's not a materialized view, but only a kind of update-operation for some text, I would guess the database shouldn't need much performance for this.

Has anyone got any experience with this?

Comment: huh?!?  Your question is rather unclear.  Can you edit and provide a better narrative of what your process is, what you are trying to do, its purpose -- yet hold back specifics that may be confidential.  Your question is as jumbled up to not adequately follow.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have "materialized views".  When you `SELECT` from a view, it performs the underlying `SELECT` dynamically.

If you are modifying the *definition* of the `VIEW`, well, that just sounds wrong.  If you need to "pass a parameter" to the view, consider using a Stored Procedure.  You can pass argument(s) in and construct a query on the fly.

Please provide more specifics.